# Rhythmbox was erased after update and cant reinstall

Tags: rhythmbox

I tried to update my rhythmbox when all of a sudden I realized it was removed from my system. I tried installing it again but I keep getting a messages for unmet dependencies.

> 

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
rhythmbox : Depends: libmusicbrainz4-3 but it is not installable
Recommends: rhythmbox-mozilla but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: rhythmbox-plugins but it is not going to be installed 

And

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

rhythmbox: Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.2.0) but 3.6.0-0ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
Depends: libmusicbrainz4-3 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: librhythmbox-core6 (= 2.98.really.2.97-1ubuntu6.1~precise1) but 2.98.really.2.97-1ubuntu6.1~precise1 is to be installed
Depends: rhythmbox-data (= 2.98.really.2.97-1ubuntu6.1~precise1) but 2.98.really.2.97-1ubuntu6.1~precise1 is to be installed
Depends: gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 2.98.really.2.97-1ubuntu6.1~precise1) but 2.98.really.2.97-1ubuntu6.1~precise1 is to be installed
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Have you tried it again now that 13.04 has been released?